# Displaying parent nodes with child nodes - nested views, hard coding, or other approach?

Tags: views, display-suite

I have a parent content type which is categorized with a taxonomy term. Then there are child nodes to the parent. When someone clicks on a category, I want them to see a table basically. It would be of the form:

> Parent1
>   Description
>
> > Child1
> >       Description
> >
> > Child2
> >       Description
>
> Parent2
>   etc

Seems out of the box I can't get Views to behave that way, so I was thinking I would have one view that is for the Parents, and another for children of a parent, and then somehow (via Display Suite for instance) have the page display the views one after another. Though I suspect that way of thinking is counter to what drupal is all about, so I am really trying to harnass the power of drupal to make that happen, as opposed to writing a custom module (though in the end I think such a custom module would be easier than Views, but I want to max out my understanding of Views before I go that route).

That said, how would you go about creating the Views and then controlling the display in Display Suite?

EDIT: So I figured out the SQL query that would return the results how I want them. Basically something like this

```
SELECT n.title, d.field_description_value, n.nid, l.field_lesson_target_id from drupal_node n

JOIN drupal_field_data_field_description AS d ON d.entity_id = n.nid

JOIN drupal_taxonomy_index AS t ON t.nid = n.nid

LEFT JOIN drupal_field_data_field_lesson AS l ON l.entity_id = n.nid

ORDER BY COALESCE(l.field_lesson_target_id, n.nid), l.field_lesson_target_id, n.nid
```

I made [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/88f80/10)

So I guess it comes down to whether Views is able to produce such queries.

Comment: How you got parent and child nodes connected together? Entity reference or something like that?

Comment: Yes, Entity Reference field links them

Comment: @BrianHuether I would recommend adding a relationship and then the necessary titles (first title field would be parent, second tie to the relationship). Then you can group by the title (of the parent).

Comment: @AlexLaughnan I agree with your solution. OP can in addition override a views theme template for the grouping. Using tables means Views will use fields which rules DS pretty much out.

Comment: The only relationship that will be available to select is taxonomy term. Which results in Views viewing both parent and child equally. Or I might be missing some deeper nuance about Views...

Comment: @BrianHuether you would add the relationship of "content referencing taxonomy term" (or something of that ilk, I don't have it off the top of my head). You can group by PARENT node ID in your display settings (for unformatted, html list, etc.).

Comment: Right now, with this approach, Views results in a display of all nodes for a given taxonomy term, I want views to display, for a given term, the lesson title, summary, then underneath, exercise titles and summaries linked to the lesson. Been experimenting with building a query of joins on the node table, body table, and entity reference field table, so I have a resulting table of node titles, summaries, nodeids, and parent ids (i.e. entity reference field target ids), which I would then have to use a self join to get the hierarchy ordering. And I am just not seeing how Views can tackle that.

Comment: @AlexLaughnan Ahhh, ok I figured it out sort of in Views. This article helped a lot: [link] (http://drupaleasy.com/blogs/ultimike/2009/02/displaying-hierarchical-content). In reading that I see that you recommend the same approach basically. I just wasn't seeing how to select both titles separately. Now I have to figure out if it will still work when I add description fields for both the parent and child node.

Answer (score 0):

Per the creator, the answer is in the comments with some additional documentation here: http://drupaleasy.com/blogs/ultimike/2009/02/displaying-hierarchical-content